# How can I adjust 2 plot with one button in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, button, click

I'm just studying Python for a month and have no experience.
I'm trying to hide/show two graphs with one Check button in matplotlib. But with my code, when clicking the button, there is only one graph hidden. Please see my code and show me my mistake.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib.widgets import Button, RadioButtons, CheckButtons

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
p = ax.scatter(5,6,7) and ax.scatter(1,2,3, color='red', marker='+', s=1e2)

lines = [p]
labels = ["Hide/Show"]

def func1(label):
    index = labels.index(label)
    lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())
    fig.canvas.draw()

a = [True]

# xposition, yposition, width, height
ax_check = plt.axes([0, 0.01, 0.25, 0.25])
plot_button = CheckButtons(ax_check, labels, a)
plot_button.on_clicked(func1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: the checkbox looks like it is working.  did you want a second check box for the second data series ?

Comment: also, you can not implement the `and` like that (it is a logical and as opposed to "this line and that line"). if you want two lines you need to plot both explicitly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ D.L Your suggestion is perfect.

Just add another line to the figure and in the function `fun1` add a calling of the line 2:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib.widgets import Button, RadioButtons, CheckButtons

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
p1 = ax.scatter(5,6,7) 
p2 = ax.scatter(1,2,3, color='red', marker='+', s=1e2)

lines = [p1, p2]
labels = ["Hide/Show"]

def func1(label):
        index = labels.index(label)
        lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())
        lines[index+1].set_visible(not lines[index+1].get_visible())
        fig.canvas.draw()

a = [True]

# xposition, yposition, width, height
ax_check = plt.axes([0, 0.01, 0.25, 0.25])
plot_button = CheckButtons(ax_check, labels, a)
plot_button.on_clicked(func1)

plt.show()
```